# PHP session across multiple domains

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have a webservice (abc.com) for my company with an own user database and it is working just fine. Now my company wants to add some additional services which are located on a completly different server with another domain (xyz.com) but still use the same login data from abc.com because we have complete control over it and there are going to be similar servers like xyz.com so it is out of question to just import the user database on xyz.com.

My first thought was to use my checkuser.php from abc.com while submitting the login form from xyz.com but then I learned that the session cookie stuff is bound to the domain. At least that is how I understood it.

After that I wanted to access my checkuser.php via AJAX and HTTPS and submit the session data encrypted via POST to xyz.com. That failed too as AJAX seems not to work across multiple servers for security reasons.

Now I am out of ideas and dont know how I can securly authenticate out users on the foreign servers using our user database.

Comment: You can use php curl for it to post from 1 domain to another http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use single sign on (SSO) in stead of a shared session. That way, you don't make the sites code dependent on each other. If you later decide to change something on one of the sites, there is less reason to worry about breaking functionality on the other sites, and if you choose to link in a new site you are able to reuse the same solution.

What's better is that someone already made it for you, and it may even be more secure that what you'll be able to create yourself.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) has some good general knowledge on SSO. Also, look into OAuth and OpenID. Combine these terms with PHP and a search should get you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you! I found this SSO library (https://github.com/jasny/SSO) and it is easy to use. Now I just have to adopt it for my uses :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to simply have the login function on xyz.com connect directly to the database of abc.com to check the login name and password. Then you use xyz.com's database for everything else. Also if you really wanted to you could store the session information in your database on abc.com instead of a temporary file then you can also access that data from xyz.com. [Here](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/session-handler.html) is an example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been working with php very long and have not encountered this problem myself, however, I've been hitting the books hard and came across an answer that my help you out.

If you are just trying to access the scripts and DB on server xyz.com, you can literally grab the content of a script using its url or IP address from within a script located on a separate server (abc.com) using the following function:

```
/* This example allows my example script on server mvc.com
to access the script on oreilly.com */
file_get_contents("http://oreilly.com");
```

Since you are accessing the code remotely, and I'm taking a shot in the dark here, I think that **file_get_contents ( )** would allow you to set variables via $_POST or $_GET methods from the script on server xyz.com and send the values to the script on server abc.com. From there, you could then store these variables inside $_SESSION variables located on a single server, which ever server that handles the original $_SESSION variables and most of the processing.

It could become a quite complex 'game of catch' between the servers if you need to go back and forth frequently, but I think it may be a way around your problem if you can't move the data onto a single server. If you plan the structure of your scripts well this would allow you to store those $_SESSION variables all in a single place.